# Inventry Form Not Updating itself after Save data C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I want to include screen shots but stack overflow not letting me to do that.Hope I am clear to you in this way.In my application I want to autofill remaining text boxes if user name is already present in the SQLite database.Like in below code

```
 private void cname_txt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
            // open connection to database 
            try
            {
                sqliteCon.Open();
                string Query = "select * from OwnerDetails where Name='" + cname_txt.Text + "' ";
                SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliteCon);
                SQLiteDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string Name = dr.GetString(0);
                    string Agency = dr.GetString(1);
                    string CellNo = dr.GetString(2);
                    string Office = dr.GetString(3);
                    string Email = dr.GetString(4);
                    string Address = dr.GetString(5);
                    cname_txt.Text = Name;
                    cagency_txt.Text = Agency;
                    ccellno_txt.Text = CellNo;
                    coffice_txt.Text = Office;
                    cemail_txt.Text = Email;
                    caddress_txt.Text = Address;

               }
                sqliteCon.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

But my Application not updating itself from database recent values.
I need to close application and then reopen it . Then it will show data in the autocomplete Name textbox.
I have tried

```
this.refresh();
this.dispose();
this.hide();
```

almost all to main application but main application is not refreshing to new database values 
I know I need to put any update query in the save button code but I am unable to do that.
Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok (i don't have sqlite to test). Are you sure, that the line

```
cname_txt.Text = Name;
```

really is reached? May be nothing is found in the database.

Comment: Yes this is correct because when i close my application and reopen it name show recent save and autfill all the below field. But not doing the above without closing application

Comment: But when you close your application it will fill the fields not by the code above, or? Nobody pressed enter. Set a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: I think it will get complicated in this way.My basic question is how we can update or you can say refresh our forms after every transaction ? For Example when I save data in field "Name" value "Dieter Meemken" and I press save button (saved successfully)and then again I want to autocomplete "Dieter Meemken" in the field "Name" by entering value Die it will autocomplete from database UNTIL I close the application and again open it

Comment: I think you're right. If the line is reached, then the problem must be outside the code you provided to us. Because when the end of the KeyDown event handler is reached, the Control is given back to the application and it's message loop. And then the textbox will be refreshed.

Comment: any suggestion how to do that