# How to update inventory form after every transaction for autocomplete etc

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I update my form autocomplete source with database after every transaction (i.e saving data etc).  I am not been able to autocomplete with the data I just save until I close application and reopen it.

I am using C#, winform, SQLite:

```
public DataForm() { 
   InitializeComponent(); 
   AutoCompleteTextPlot(); 
   AutoCompleteTextLocation(); 
   AutoCompleteTextSize(); 
   AutoCompleteTextComArea(); 
   AutoCompleteTextRemarks(); 
   AutoCompleteTextOwnerName(); 
   AutoCompleteTextCustomerName(); 
}
```

Comment: sure would help if you show us what your currently doing..

Comment: Are you pre-loading values from the database to assist in autocomplete functionality or are you doing lookups against your database as data is keyed in?  You really should include some code so your problem is more easily understood.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905587/inventry-form-not-updating-itself-after-save-data-c-sharp-winform/33905780?noredirect=1#comment55614014_33905780)
you can check here

Comment: @KrisOye I am pre-loading values like `public DataForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AutoCompleteTextPlot();
            AutoCompleteTextLocation();
            AutoCompleteTextSize();
            AutoCompleteTextComArea();
            AutoCompleteTextRemarks();
            AutoCompleteTextOwnerName();
            AutoCompleteTextCustomerName();
        }`

Comment: ``@MethodMan I just want to know is there any way update form with recent data change in the database with queries like `this.refresh()` or `this.update()` ? by the way both are not working in my case.And I just commented the code please have a look

Answer (score 0):

So you don't appear to reload the data source after you've submitted the form.  It feels a bit heavy-handed but you could reload all of your autoloading hints after a successful submission:

```
public DataForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeAutocomplete(() => InitializeAutocomplete(tbName, "OwnerName", "Owners"));
    InitializeAutocomplete(() => InitializeAutocomplete(tbRemarks, "RemarkText", "Remarks"));
}

List<Action> autoCompleteInitializers = new List<Action>();

private void ReinitializeAutocomplete()
{
    foreach(var initializer in autoCompleteInitializers)
    {
        initializer();
    }
}

private void InitializeAutocomplete(Action init)
{
    init();
    autoCompleteInitializers.Add(init);
}

private void InitializeAutocomplete(TextBox tb, string fieldName, string tableName)
{
    tb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    tb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    using (SQLiteConnection dbconn = new SQLiteConnection())
    {
        dbconn.Open();
        using (SQLiteCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand())
        {
            dbcmd.CommandText = String.Format("select {0} from {1}", fieldName, tableName);
            dbcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (SQLiteDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(reader[fieldName].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bTransactionSuccess) ReinitializeAutocomplete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time my problem solved by using all functions call for example `AutoCompleteTextPlot(); AutoCompleteTextLocation(); AutoCompleteTextSize(); ` in the save button code